# how to Execute multiple shell commands in tsystem component talend

Tags: shell, centos6, talend

My Talend open Studio For Data Integreation version 6.0
 And Platform Cent OS 6.5

I was trying to execute multiple shell commands in tsystem component

"cp -f -v dir1 dir2 ; cp -f -v dir3 dir4"

I was getting error

cp: cannot stat `;': No such file or directory

In windows Enironment I tried and it was fine.

"cmd /c xcopy "c:/folder1" "d:/folder2" /y /f /I & xcopy "c:/folder3" "d:/folder4" /y /f /I"

Could you guid me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux env you can use this:

```
new String[] {"/bin/bash","-c","cp -f -v dir1 dir2 ","cp -f -v dir3 dir4"}
```

or choose the array command in the tSystem component, and put each element of the previous array in a separated line.
If this not work, you can use tForEach before tSystem to iterate over many commands that are stored in the tForEach component:

```
tForEach-----(iterate)-------tSystem---..
```

Comment: I tried both options(Single command and Array command) but only first command is working(cp -f -v dir1 dir2).